# Como detectar quando o usuário tentar acessar uma URL sem ter uma ROLE para aquela URL no Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

No meu sistema as ROLES das urls das telas são carregadas dinamicamente do banco de dados através de um `ObjectPOstProcessor` como vocês podem ver abaixo:

```
    public void configProducao(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AffirmativeBased affirmativeBased = new AffirmativeBased(Arrays.asList(new RoleVoter(), new WebExpressionVoter()));
        http
        .csrf().disable()
           .authorizeRequests()
           .accessDecisionManager(affirmativeBased)
              .antMatchers("/backend/ui/", "/backend/ui/auth/**", "/resource/**").permitAll()
              .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .withObjectPostProcessor(new ObjectPostProcessor<FilterSecurityInterceptor>() {
                    @Override
                    public <O extends FilterSecurityInterceptor> O postProcess (O fsi) {
                        fsi.setSecurityMetadataSource(dynamicSecurityMetadataSource);
                        return fsi;
                    }
                })
           .and()
        .formLogin()
           .loginPage("/backend/ui/")
           .permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout()
           .invalidateHttpSession(true)
           .clearAuthentication(true)
           .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/backend/ui/logout/"))
           .logoutSuccessUrl("/backend/ui/")
           .permitAll();
    }
```

E ele faz a verificação através de uma classe que implementa `FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource`

```
    @Component
public class DynamicSecurityMetadataSource implements FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource {

    @Autowired
    private TelaRepository telaRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PerfilRepository perfilRepository;

    private static final FogasTracer tracer = new FogasTracer(DynamicSecurityMetadataSource.class);

    @Override
    public Collection<ConfigAttribute> getAttributes(Object object) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        final HttpServletRequest request = ((FilterInvocation) object).getRequest();

        String url = request.getRequestURI();
        url = url.replace("/backend/ui", "");

        Optional<String> urlEncontrada = telaRepository.getUrlTela(url);

        tracer.info(urlEncontrada);

        if (urlEncontrada.isPresent()) {
            Set<String> rolesDaTela = perfilRepository.getPerfisQueTemAcessoTela(urlEncontrada.get());
            Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes = new HashSet<>();

            for (String role : rolesDaTela) {
                tracer.info(role);
                attributes.add(new SecurityConfig(role));
            }

            return attributes;
        }

        return null;
        }

       @Override
       public Collection<ConfigAttribute> getAllConfigAttributes() {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           return null;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
           return FilterInvocation.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
       }

    }
```

como vocês podem ver no método `getAttributes()` eu já consigo buscar as url e restringir pela `ROLE` do banco, o meu problema é que quando um usuário tenta acessar uma url sem ter a role necessária o spring me joga para uma página de erro padrão (`/error`), sendo que eu gostaria de redirecionar o usuário para uma página de acesso negado que eu já tenho implementada. Como eu consigo fazer a verificação de quando o usuário tentou acessar uma página a qual ele não tem acesso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o meu problema de uma maneira bem simples até, no método `configProducao()` coloquei apenas um exceptionHandling como vocês podem ver abaixo:

```
.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/backend/ui/unauthorized")
```

implementação completa:

```
public void configProducao(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    AffirmativeBased affirmativeBased = new AffirmativeBased(Arrays.asList(new RoleVoter(), new WebExpressionVoter()));
    http
    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/backend/ui/unauthorized")
    .and()
    .csrf().disable()
       .authorizeRequests()
       .accessDecisionManager(affirmativeBased)
          .antMatchers("/backend/ui/", "/backend/ui/auth/**", "/resource/**").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .withObjectPostProcessor(new ObjectPostProcessor<FilterSecurityInterceptor>() {
                @Override
                public <O extends FilterSecurityInterceptor> O postProcess (O fsi) {
                    fsi.setSecurityMetadataSource(dynamicSecurityMetadataSource);
                    return fsi;
                }
            })
       .and()
    .formLogin()
       .loginPage("/backend/ui/")
       .permitAll()
    .and()
    .logout()
       .invalidateHttpSession(true)
       .clearAuthentication(true)
       .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/backend/ui/logout/"))
       .logoutSuccessUrl("/backend/ui/")
       .permitAll();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode também implementar a annotation `@Secured` nos métodos que dependem de roles específicas (controladoras, services...).

```
@Secured ({"ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN"})
public void meuMetodoSeguroPorRoles() {
   ...
}
```

Detalhes da implementação podem ser vistas na [documentação](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/annotation/Secured.html).